# keep indexes of original array of floats at sorting, and reverse sort to get back the original array afterwards js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, indexing

I have this particular array of floats

`segm3 = [0.0, 2.5, 3.62, 0.0, 2.5, 3.62, 0.0]`

I desire to sort it while keeping the original indexes. This is my code:

```
var indices = Array.from(Array(segm3.length).keys())
.sort(function(a,b) { if (segm3[a] > segm3[b]) return 1;
 else if (segm3[a]<segm3[b]) return -1 ;else return 0;})
```

when I try to console.log the indexes I get this

```
[
  0, 3, 6, 1,
  4, 2, 5
]
```

It should be right, but after I sort segm3 how can I return back to form the original segm3 with the use of the indexes list ?

Answer (score 0):

To keep the original indexes you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

Code:

```js
const segm3 = [0.0, 2.5, 3.62, 0.0, 2.5, 3.62, 0.0]

const segm3SortedWithIndexes = segm3
  .map((f, i) => ({
    floatNumber: f,
    index: i, // <-- original index
  }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.floatNumber - b.floatNumber)
  
console.log('"segm3" with original index:', segm3SortedWithIndexes)

const result = segm3SortedWithIndexes.map(({ floatNumber: f }) => f)

console.log('"segm3" sorted:', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

after `segm3.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b})`

just

```
let resultArr;
for(var i=0;i<indices.length;i++){
        resultArr[indices[i]]=segm3[i]
    }
```

It was simple as that but my mind was melt

Answer (score 0):

Having got the indices sorted according to the values in `segm3`, if you then sort `segm3` you can then restore the original ordering of `segm3` by using the `indices` array to extract the values from the sorted `segm3` array:

```js
const segm3 = [0.0, 2.5, 3.62, 0.0, 2.5, 3.62, 0.0]
console.log(JSON.stringify(segm3))

let indices = Array.from(Array(segm3.length).keys())
  .sort((a,b) => segm3[a] - segm3[b])

console.log(JSON.stringify(indices))

segm3.sort((a,b) => a - b);
console.log(JSON.stringify(segm3))

let origsegm3 = indices.map(i => segm3[i])
console.log(JSON.stringify(origsegm3))
```